# Access control and static members

Tags: c++

I was reading about acces specifiers for static member functions, and ended up with this example from MSDN: which I think has an error.

```
// access_control.cpp  
class Base  
{  
 public:  
  int Print();             // Nonstatic member.  
   static int CountOf();    // Static member.  
};  


class Derived1 : private Base  
{  
};  

class Derived2 : public Derived1  
{  
  int ShowCount();    // Nonstatic member.  
};  

int Derived2::ShowCount()  
{  
  // Call static member function CountOf explicitly.  
  int cCount = Base::CountOf();     // OK.  

  // Call static member function CountOf using pointer.  
   cCount = this->CountOf();  // C2247. Conversion of  
                           //  Derived2 * to Base * not  
                           //  permitted.  
   return cCount;  
}
```

So it said that this line is Ok bu it's not :

```
int cCount = Base::CountOf();     // OK.
```

and this is the error msg :

```
error C2247: 'Base::CountOf' not accessible because 'Derived1' uses 'private' to inherit from 'Base'
```

So does the error really exists or is it related to some Option that I have to add when compiling?

Thx

Comment: Yes, the error really exists. CountOf is private in derived1, and so also in derived2.

Comment: `int cCount = Base::CountOf();` is also an error

Comment: @Butterworth so even for static member funtions the acees depends on the access specifier in the head of inheritence. ?

Comment: Why would access for static members be any different than that for non-static ones?

Comment: If you got this code from somewhere then it would be good to link to the source

Comment: @M.M : this is a link to the source  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kktasw36.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a similar example to your code, in the C++17 Standard section [class.access.base]/3:

> A member of a private base class might be inaccessible as an inherited member name, but accessible directly. Because of the rules on pointer conversions (7.11) and explicit casts (8.4), a conversion from a pointer to a derived class to a pointer to an inaccessible base class might be ill-formed if an implicit conversion is used, but well-formed if an explicit cast is used. For example,

```
class B {
public:
    int mi; // non-static member
    static int si; // static member
};
class D : private B {
};
class DD : public D {
    void f();
};

void DD::f() {
    mi = 3; // error: mi is private in D
    si = 3; // error: si is private in D
    ::B b;
    b.mi = 3; // OK (b.mi is different from this->mi)
    b.si = 3; // OK (b.si is different from this->si)
    ::B::si = 3; // OK
    ::B* bp1 = this; // error: B is a private base class
    ::B* bp2 = (::B*)this; // OK with cast
    bp2->mi = 3; // OK: access through a pointer to B.
}
```

---

Your code differs from this in that you do `Base::CountOf()`. This is still an error because access is checked in the context of `Derived2`, and there is no access rights to private members of a base class.

However `::Base::CountOf()` would be correct because then access is checked in the global namespace.

You can fix the second part of your example in a similar way to the Standard's example: `(::Base *)this)->CountOf()`.

Comment: yup that's more clear and It works if I change the access to global. ::BaseClass::PublicStatic();